# How to call functions in chrome-extension from tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to call functions defined in the chrome-extension popup.js or background.js using the inserted button.

```
[popup.js]
var injectCode = "
 var createNode = document.createElement('div');
 createNode.setAttribute('id', 'chromeExtensionModule_runBtn');
 document.body.appendChild(createNode); ";

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {code: injectCode}, errorhandle);

function myExtensionFunc(){ ~ };
```

How to call myExtensionFunc()?

Comment: Please [edit] you question to be a bit more clear. As I understand what you desire is to call the `myExtensionFunc()` which exists in your popup or background scripts from a content script. You can't do that. They are in separate contexts and almost always in separate processes. You have to send messages asking for *data* to be transmitted. You could send the function as a string and execute that code in the content script context. Is that what you desire?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right. I knew that if the Chrome extension was running, I would be able to access the program running on the Chrome browser tab. They are separate processes. I know I can inject it with the contents of the function. However, this does not work on the injected page, as it must accept an external library's authentication token. Tokens can only be obtained within my Chrome extension. So I was looking for a way to run a function on my Chrome extension via a web page.

Comment: `run a function on my Chrome extension via a web page` - I can't parse this. Anyway, since the processes are different all you can do is to use message passing.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I am not good at English. Lol.

run a function on my Chrome extension via a web page - 
A(any webpage)  ,  B(Chrome-extention){..B.func1(), B.func2()...} 
                         A  <==  inject(anything) , 
A request(B.func1) ==> B run(func1)

Okay! I'll look for message passing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function on a button click, attach an `onClick` event handler to your button.

i.e. `document.getElementById('chromeExtensionModule_runBtn').onClick = myExtensionFunc;`

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, the documents are different. I can't find the module in Google-extension-program on the injected tab. I would like to run the module in the Google-extension-program with the button I created if the extension was installed. If it does not work, It is good in any way. Can not run modules in Google Extensions through documents loaded on the Chrome browser tab? 
I have no experience developing Google extensions.

Comment: @wendy What do you mean by "module"? Do you mean [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)?

Comment: Sorry. module is function in Chrome-extension-program.
I also made a mistake on the above. This is a chrome-extension, not a google-extension.